# How to calculate the size needed for formated wchar array, `CRT_SECURE` way?

Tags: c++, format, wchar-t

I need to calculate the size need for formated wchar array.
Consider following code:

```
wchar_t* Format(const wchar_t* format, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);

    wchar_t *w = NULL;
    int len = _vsnwprintf(NULL, 0, format, args) + 1;            // <------ Error
    if (len > 0)
    {
        w = new wchar_t[len];
        w[0] = 0;
        _vsnwprintf_s(w, len, len, format, args);
    }
    va_end(args);

    return w;
}
```

if `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` is turned on, above code work, if not, the error say:

> '_vsnwprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using
>   _vsnwprintf_s instead.

But I can not manage to use `_vsnwprintf_s` to calculate the size needed for the wchar buffer.

Following is what I tried:

```
int len = _vsnwprintf_s(NULL, 0, 0, format, args); // return 1

// debug assertion failed: string != NULL && DstSizeInWords > 0
int len = _vsnwprintf_s(NULL, 0, INT_MAX, format, args);

// debug assertion failed: string != NULL && DstSizeInWords > 0
int len = _vsnwprintf_s(NULL, INT_MAX, 0, format, args);

// debug assertion failed: string != NULL && DstSizeInWords > 0
int len = _vsnwprintf_s(NULL, INT_MAX, INT_MAX, format, args);
```

Other function: `_snwprintf` give `_CRT_SECURE` error and `_snwprintf_s` have same effect with `_vsnwprintf_s`

### Question:

Although I pretty okay with `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` turned on, I wonder how can I calculate the size needed for formated wchar array, `CRT_SECURE` way? Note that it must accept `va_list` as agrument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to obtain required buffer size using [`_vscwprintf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/vscprintf-vscprintf-l-vscwprintf-vscwprintf-l):

```
_Check_return_ _Ret_z_ wchar_t *
Format(_Printf_format_string_ _In_z_ wchar_t const * const psz_format, ...)
{
    size_t formatted_string_length;
    va_list args;
    {
        va_start(args, psz_format);
        int const result(::_vscwprintf(psz_format, args));
        va_end(args);
        if(-1 == result)
        {
            ::abort();
        }
        assert(0 <= result);
        formatted_string_length = static_cast< size_t >(result);
    }
    size_t const buffer_size(formatted_string_length + 1u);
    wchar_t * const p_buffer(new wchar_t[buffer_size]);
    {
        va_start(args, psz_format);
        int const result(::_vsnwprintf_s(p_buffer, buffer_size, formatted_string_length, psz_format, args));
        va_end(args);
        if(-1 == result)
        {
            ::abort();
        }
        assert(0 <= result);
        assert(static_cast< size_t >(result) == formatted_string_length);
        assert(L'\0' == p_buffer[formatted_string_length]);
    }
    return p_buffer;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I need. Thank you very much!